# How do I scroll my recyclerview to the top when items order has changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxBmu.png).I am sorting that list based on the selected chip.Here is my sorting code:

`SortingUtil`

```
enum class SortingUtil {
    DESCBYTOTALCASES,
    ASCBYTOTALCASES,
    DESCBYDEATHCASES,
    ASCBYDEATHCASES,
    DESCBYALPHA,
    ASCBYALPHA
}
```

`CountriesFragment`

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var mAdapter: CountriesFragmentAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initRecycler()
        observeViewModel()
        initChips()

    }
  private fun initChips() {
        binding.chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.totalDesc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.DESCBYTOTALCASES)
                }
                R.id.totalAsc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.ASCBYTOTALCASES)
                }
                R.id.deathDesc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.DESCBYDEATHCASES)
                }
                R.id.deathAsc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.ASCBYDEATHCASES)
                }
                R.id.alphaDesc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.DESCBYALPHA)
                }
                R.id.alphaAsc -> {
                    mViewModel.rearangeCountries(SortingUtil.ASCBYALPHA)
                }
            }
        }
    }
 private fun observeViewModel() {
        mViewModel.countries.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { resource ->
            when (resource) {
                is Resource.Loading -> showProgress()
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgress()
                    SnackUtil.showSnackbar(
                        requireContext(),
                        requireView(),
                        resource.message.toString(),
                        R.color.color_danger
                    )
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgress()
                    mViewModel.setCountryList(resource.data!!)
                }
            }
        }
        mViewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { countryList ->
            mAdapter.diff.submitList(countryList)
        }
    }
```

`CountriesFragmentViewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class CountriesFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: Repo
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _countries = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<CountryResponse>>>()

    val countries: LiveData<Resource<List<CountryResponse>>> get() = _countries

    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<CountryResponse>>()

    private val countryList = MutableLiveData<List<CountryResponse>>()

    private var currentOrder = SortingUtil.DESCBYTOTALCASES

    init {
        getCountries()
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(countryList) { countries ->
            countries.let {
                mediatorLiveData.value = sortList(it, currentOrder)
            }
        }
    }

    fun rearangeCountries(order: SortingUtil) = countryList.value.let {
        mediatorLiveData.value = sortList(it!!, order)
    }.also {
        currentOrder = order
    }

    fun getCountries() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _countries.value = repo.getCountries()
        }
    }

    fun setCountryList(list: List<CountryResponse>) {
        countryList.value = list
    }

    private fun sortList(
        countryList: List<CountryResponse>,
        order: SortingUtil
    ): List<CountryResponse> {
        when (order) {
            SortingUtil.DESCBYTOTALCASES -> {
                return countryList.sortedByDescending {
                    it.cases
                }
            }
            SortingUtil.ASCBYTOTALCASES -> {
                return countryList.sortedBy {
                    it.cases
                }
            }
            SortingUtil.DESCBYDEATHCASES -> {
                return countryList.sortedByDescending {
                    it.deaths
                }
            }
            SortingUtil.ASCBYDEATHCASES -> {
                return countryList.sortedBy {
                    it.deaths
                }
            }
            SortingUtil.DESCBYALPHA -> {
                return countryList.sortedByDescending {
                    it.country
                }
            }
            SortingUtil.ASCBYALPHA -> {
                return countryList.sortedBy {
                    it.country
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

`CountriesFragmentAdapter`

```
@FragmentScoped
class CountriesFragmentAdapter @Inject constructor() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CountryResponse>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CountryResponse, newItem: CountryResponse): Boolean =
            oldItem.countryInfo.id == newItem.countryInfo.id


        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: CountryResponse,
            newItem: CountryResponse
        ): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

    }

    val diff = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): CountriesFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            CountryItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = diff.currentList[position]
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = diff.currentList.size

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: CountryItemLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(countryResponse: CountryResponse) {
            binding.apply {
                Glide.with(itemView.context)
                    .load(countryResponse.countryInfo.flag)
                    .into(binding.countryFlagIv)
                countryNameTv.text = countryResponse.country
                totalCasesTv.text = formatStat(countryResponse.cases)
                totalDeathsTv.text = formatStat(countryResponse.deaths)
            }
        }

        private fun formatStat(stat: Long): String = "%,d".format(stat)
    }
}
```

My sorting logic is working as expected.My problem is when my items rearranged, my `recyclerview` is getting just some random position.I want to scroll my `recyclerview` to the top when items rearranged.I have also tried `binding.countryRv.scrollToPosition(0)` but it did not work.

Comment: This is happening because you are sorting the list separately, assign the sorted list to the adapter

Comment: @drjansari I am already assigning sorted list to the adapter with `       mViewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { countryList ->
            mAdapter.diff.submitList(countryList)
        }`

Comment: Can you post the adapter code as well to analyze more

Comment: @drjansari okay I have added my adapter code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862743/4168607

Comment: @ADM thanks for reference. I actually solved my problem using `mAdapter.diff.addListListener { _, _ -> binding.countriesRv.scrollToPosition(0)}` but I am not sure if this is the correct way.