# Is there a way in which we can swipe the recycler view all the item at once on button click with the help of ItemTouchHelper?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is button in which user can tap then all the recycler view item get swiped at once. And also have capability of manual swipe on recycler view item.

Comment: is button inside or outside of recycler view ?

Comment: Outside of the recycler view

Comment: Try this when you click button
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862743/19491703